# Sentence formation of a past incident

Tags: past-tense, progressive-aspect, sequence-of-tenses

I need help with finding out which of the below sentences is correct:

1. Since she wore glasses, I could not discern whether she **was crying**.
2. Since she wore glasses, I could not discern whether she **cried**.

Are both the sentences correct? If so, when to use which sentence?

Answer (score -1):

The first lacks harmony between the verbs. It would work better if it began "Since she was wearing glasses..."

However, both can work as saying "she wore glasses" (in general) and that you couldn't tell if she was crying (at that particular moment) also gives the implication that that particular moment was no exception and she was wearing them then too.

So 1 can work, but it would be better by making it explicit.

We really could do with more context as this is what really establishes aspect.

Comment: Definitely 'was crying' rather than 'cried'.

Comment: If you believe so, then provide a *reasoned* answer. An unsubstantiated disagreement in no way helps the OP and other readers understand. Same goes for the silent downvoters.

Comment: You said in your own answer 'you couldn't tell if she was crying' - the reason being that it's idiomatic English!

Comment: I'd argue against "definitely". Context is a major player.